# Check if domnodelist->item(x)->nodeValue == "nbsp;"

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I have logged in to, and grabbed the return page using `CURL`, loaded it with `DOMDocument` and then queried it with `DOMXPATH` (to find 'table.essgrid tr'). (I am then also querying the result to find child 'td's and) with the results, `results->item(2)->nodeValue` is either a date or what echos in browser as `&nbsp;` or . I need to check if it will be a non break space or actual text.

Hopefully that makes some sense with the code below.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($result);

$xpath = new DOMXPATH($dom);
$result = $xpath->query('//table[@class="essgrid"]//tr');
if($result->length > 0) {
    foreach($result as $item) {
        $tds = $item->getElementsByTagName('td');

        if($tds->length) {
            if($tds->item(2)->nodeValue != "&nbsp;" && $tds->item(2)->nodeValue != " ") {
                echo = '<div>not blank:</div>';
                echo = '<div>'.$tds->item(2)->nodeValue.'</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I am wanting this to only echo the "table.essgrid>tr>td" that have a value that isnt a non-breaking space, but it just echos this onto the page:

```
<div>not blank:</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>not blank:</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>not blank:</div>
<div>13:00</div>
<div>not blank:</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>not blank:</div>
<div>14:30</div>
<div>not blank:</div>
<div>13:00</div>
<div>not blank:</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

But it is echoing all the results, not just the ones with a time. So I think my problem is checking if the value == `&nbsp;`, but nothing I have tried in its place seems to work.

Comment: Well, entities might be expanded. Can you show the actual HTML, or the URL?

Comment: Try using `textContent` instead of `nodeValue`, as the text will be in a text node inside the `td` node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to compare `nodeValue` for being `&nbsp;`, you need to know two things:

1. `&nbsp;` is a HTML entity that represents a specific character, here the *non-breaking space* which could be formally specified as [Unicode Character 'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm).
2. The *DOMDocument* library uses UTF-8 as character encoding when giving or accepting string values.

With this general information at hand, it's easy to solve your problem. As `&nbsp;` stands for *NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0)* and as `DOMElement::nodeValue` returns the contents as UTF-8 encoded string and as *NO-BREAK SPACE* in UTF-8 is `"\xC2\xA0"` in PHP you can simply compare it:

```
/** @var $td DOMElement */
$td = $tds->item(2);
if ($td->nodeValue !== "\xC2\xA0") {
    // TD content is not "&nbsp;"
}
```

Hope this gives you the needed pointers.