# PHP DOM Document ignore whitespaces appending nodeValue

Tags: php, dom, docx

I'm working with MS Office Word document through PHP and DOM. I am adding paragraphs to my document. And now I have to make the part of string bold (it becomes from database and I'm unable to change it). Like this:

> The part of string is **bold** really.

What I do:

```
    if(strpos($input, $search)) {
            $splitted  = explode($search, $input);
            $t1 = new DOMElement('t', " ".$splitted[0]." ", $this->ns);
            $t2 = new DOMElement('t', " ". $search ." ", $this->ns);
            $t3 = new DOMElement('t', " ".$splitted[1]." ", $this->ns);
}
```

And after I'm adding this element to document. BUut I'm getting:

> The part of string is**bold**really.

It removes whitespaces before and after nodeValue. I tried to force adding of spaces (as in code above). Nothing helps. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617586/check-if-domnodelist-itemx-nodevalue-nbsp) question solved the broblem

Te solution is:

```
$t1 = new DOMElement('t', $splitted[0], $this->ns);
$t2 = new DOMElement('t', "\xC2\xA0". $search ."\xC2\xA0", $this->ns);
$t3 = new DOMElement('t', $splitted[1], $this->ns);
```

Because `&nbsp;` is N HTML entity. For adding UTF-8 encoded non_breakable_space we have to use `"\xC2\xA0"`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace actual space characters with an `&nbsp;` Which doesn't break the line, but it adds a space.

```
if(strpos($input, $search)) {
        $splitted  = explode($search, $input);
        $t1 = new DOMElement('t', '&nbsp;'.$splitted[0].'&nbsp;', $this->ns);
        $t2 = new DOMElement('t', '&nbsp;'. $search .'&nbsp;', $this->ns);
        $t3 = new DOMElement('t', '&nbsp;'.$splitted[1].'&nbsp;', $this->ns);
}
```

Comment: @Steve.B Sorry... you might need to escape the & character. Have you tried putting a \ before the &

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer to make it more in-depth.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing your spaces in strings with an " " string. This is HTML equivalent for a "space" so to speak.

so instead of:

```
$t1 = new DOMElement('t', " ".$splitted[0]." ", $this->ns);
```

do:

```
$t1 = new DOMElement('t', "&nbsp;".$splitted[0]."&nbsp;", $this->ns);
```